# Not able to Upload Image in Shopify using Product Image API

Tags: shopify

I tried to create a new image using the below JSON Request and it seems to be failing.

JSON Request:

{"image": {"position":1,"attachment": "base64","filename": "ZZAR9999TEST_CHOCOLATE_1.jpg"}}

Note:i cannot copy the base64 due to the string being too large to put it here.

JSON Response:

```
{"errors":{"image":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}
```

As per the error, i am missing some Required parameter. I have no idea which Required Parameter am I missing. If someone could guide me, i would appreciate it.

Comment: Do a better job of posting your object or no one can help you. Even though you point out you did not post the Base64 data, the rest of your JSON is also chock full of errors. Try hard, redact data where needed, but be precise. You know computers only work with 1 or 0... you cannot be 0.6 and expect correctness.

Comment: @DavidLazar I have edited the JSON object, sorry about that.

Comment: Never mind, i found the solution, looks like there was already an image on position 1 and since i was doing a 'POST' request , it was failing.